# `System.Windows.Point` struct replacement with class

Tags: c#, object, .net-3.5

I need type similar to `System.Windows.Point`, but I need class, not struct.

**Background**

I tried to create few points and put them on list, and change their coordinates.

My code was equivalent to this:

```
List<Point> listofpoints = new List<Point>();

listofpoints.Add(new Point(1, 1));
listofpoints.Add(new Point(5, 5));

Line line = new Line();

line.Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

line.X1 = listofpoints[0].X;
line.Y1 = listofpoints[0].X;
line.X2 = listofpoints[1].X;
line.Y2 = listofpoints[1].X;

canvas1.Children.Add(line);


// later I had to change these points coordinates
// I tried to move shapes with these points by changing only these point properties
listofpoints[0].X = 50;
listofpoints[0].Y = 50;

// but i cant, (probably) because struct is not reference type
```

---

**What i have**

I wrote simple class that gives me ability to change points on list without replacing them with new points.

```
public class CPoint
{ 
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}
```

**What I want?**

I want this class to act like `System.Windows.Point` struct. By "act like" i mean, I want to be able create rectangle with `CPoint` like this:

```
CPoint cp1 = new CPoint();

cp1.X = 0;
cp1.Y = 0;

CPoint cp2 = new CPoint();

cp2.X = 10;
cp2.Y = 20;

Rect r = new Rect(cp1, cp2); // this is just example, in fact - I use other shapes

// i want to be able to move that rectangle by only changing cp1 and cp2 properties.
```

**Is this possible?**

Do I need some accessor? I know how to make accessor that returns some property, but I don't know how to write accessor that returns whole class.

Comment: You can use [implicit conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but AFAIK, it's not possible to make it so once you create the `Rect`, if you subsequently change `cp1.X = 9000` to have it automatically propagate to that `Rect` especially as `Rect` itself is a `struct`. I think you would have to consider a different design/usage entirely if that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: Why do you need to create a new CPoint class. What is your requirement which is not fulfilled by Point?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisSinclair. Actually - I don't use rectangles... That was just simplified example. In fact - need this for moving some weird shapes which are my custom classes, not structs. If you put your comment in answer - I will accept it. And thats good to know, that Rect is struct too.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal My problem with Point struct is that I can't change that point properties when I put it on List for example. I explained this in my comment in code.

Comment: Kamil: You might be better off storing references to the shapes themselves rather than the points. Why not store the `Line` objects in your `listofpoints`? Beyond that, you'll want to have your `CPoint` objects be given a reference to the lines they're associated with in some way (maybe via events)

Comment: @Kamil: See the edit I made to my answer. Perhaps that will help give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) operators:

```
public class CPoint
{ 
    public double X;
    public double Y;

    public static implicit operator Point(CPoint cpoint)
    {
        return new Point(cpoint.X, cpoint.Y);
    }

    public static implicit operator CPoint(Point point)
    {
        return new CPoint(point.X, point.Y);
    }
}
```

This means that wherever you try to use a `CPoint` where a `Point` is required (and vice-versa), the compiler will insert a call to those conversion operators. So your usage will be exactly as you want it:

```
Rect r = new Rect(cp1, cp2);
```

However, based on your code comment, AFAIK, it's not possible to make it so once you create the `Rect`, if you subsequently change `cp1.X = 9000` to have it automatically propagate to that `Rect` especially as `Rect` itself is a struct. I think you would have to consider a different design/usage entirely if that's what you want to achieve.

EDIT: Based on your requirements, a possible design to consider might be something like this. First, define your `CPoint` to notify when its properties changed:

```
public class CPoint
{ 
    public event Action<CPoint, double> XChanged;
    public event Action<CPoint, double> YChanged;

    private double _X;
    public double X
    {
        get { return _X; }
        set
        {
            _X = value;

            var xchanged = XChanged;
            if (xchanged != null)
                xchanged(this, value);
        }
    }

    private double _Y;
    public double Y
    {
        get { return _Y; }
        set
        {
            _Y = value;

            var ychanged = YChanged;
            if (ychanged != null)
                ychanged(this, value);
        }
    }

    public CPoint()
    {

    }

    public CPoint(double x, double y)
    {
        this._X = x;
        this._Y = y;
    }
}
```

Then, because *I think*, your intent is to share the same point with multiple lines (drawing an N-sided polygon for example), link the lines with the point:

```
List<CPoint> listofpoints = new List<CPoint>();

listofpoints.Add(new CPoint(1, 1));
listofpoints.Add(new CPoint(5, 5));

Line line = new Line();

line.Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

listofpoints[0].XChanged += (p, x) => line.X1 = x;
listofpoints[0].YChanged += (p, y) => line.Y1 = y;
listofpoints[1].XChanged += (p, x) => line.X2 = x;
listofpoints[1].YChanged += (p, y) => line.Y2 = y;

line.X1 = listofpoints[0].X;
line.Y1 = listofpoints[0].X;
line.X2 = listofpoints[1].X;
line.Y2 = listofpoints[1].X;

canvas1.Children.Add(line);
```

Notice the listeners to the `XChanged` and `YChanged` events and how they get associated with the Line's `X1`, X2`,`Y1`,`Y2` properties.

Presumably you'll also use these points for other shapes and this way they won't be tied to any one shape type.

```
listofpoints[0].X = 50; //propagates to line.X1 via the event
listofpoints[0].Y = 50; //propagates to line.Y1 via the event
```

There's a bit of duplication there with assigning the events *and* assigning the initial values to the line, but I'm sure a bit of tweaking will eliminate that if necessary.

Comment: Problem with `Rect` is not a problem. I can use `public sealed class System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` instead of `Rect`. Thanks for very valuable answer :)

Comment: Thanks for adding more information. Im not familiar enough with "advanced" C#, but this is very interesting and I have to think about it. I don't understand that weird line `listofpoints[1].YChanged += (p, y) => line.Y2 = y;`, however I will figure this out.

Comment: @Kamil: Yup, read up on events, delegates, and lambdas. You'll get there. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot move a Rectangle by mutating its constituent Points.  That is by design.
WPF *does* let you do the sort of thing that you want to do, though, through data binding and dependency properties.

For Rectangles in particular, you want to bind to the RadiusX and RadiusY properties, because they are the bindable dependency properties that Rectangle provides.

When you bind your Rectangle to a model object, make sure your model object either implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.100).aspx) or provides dependency properties of its own.

For more info on WPF data binding, look [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#basic_data_binding_concepts)

Comment: Im already moving WPF lines without binding and it works. This method will not work with Rectangle points? Thats not good...